# How to assign a random number to a user input?

Tags: javascript, html

In my code, I am trying to set up a magic eightball that outputs a random answer from my choices of cases. I was wondering if it is possible to assign a random number to a user's input then output one of the cases. I am able to assign without a user question but is it at all possible to have a user question, then disregard what they're inputting and just assign said question a random case?

````
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to ask a question.</p>

<button onclick="myEightball()">I will answer any question</button>

<p id="eightball"></p>

<script>
function myEightball() {
  var text;
  var userQuestion = prompt("What would you like to know?");
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
switch(randomNumber){
  case 1: 
  console.log('It is certain');
  break;

  case 2: 
  console.log('It is decidely so');
  break;

  case 3:
  console.log('Reply hazy try again');
  break;

  case 4:
  console.log('Cannot predict now');
  break;

  case 5:
  console.log('Do not count on it');
  break;

  case 6:
  console.log('My sources say no!');
  break;

  case 7:
  console.log('Outlook is not good');
  break;

  case 0:
  console.log('Signs point to yes!');
  break;
  
  default:
  console.log('Ask again later!');
  break;
  }
  document.getElementById("eightball").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: so, instead of `console.log('some string')` do `text = 'some string'` since you output text to the document after the switch statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.random` to generate the value. Then, select your `input` and update its `value`

Example:

```js
const rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
console.log(rando);
document.getElementById('input').value = rando;
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following by just setting the value of text variable to the string that you want to display to the user. The code for the following will go like this...

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to ask a question.</p>

<button onclick="myEightball()">I will answer any question</button>

<p id="eightball"></p>

<script>
function myEightball() {
  var text;
  var userQuestion = prompt("What would you like to know?");
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
switch(randomNumber){
  case 1: 
  console.log('It is certain');
  text = 'It is certain';
  break;

  case 2: 
  console.log('It is decidely so');
  text = 'It is decidely so';
  break;

  case 3:
  console.log('Reply hazy try again');
  text = 'Reply hazy try again';
  break;

  case 4:
  console.log('Cannot predict now');
  text = 'Cannot predict now';
  break;

  case 5:
  console.log('Do not count on it');
  text = 'Do not count on it';
  break;

  case 6:
  console.log('My sources say no!');
  text = 'My sources say no!';
  break;

  case 7:
  console.log('Outlook is not good');
  text = 'Outlook is not good';
  break;

  case 0:
  console.log('Signs point to yes!');
  text = 'Signs point to yes!';
  break;
  
  default:
  console.log('Ask again later!');
  text = 'Ask again later!';
  break;
  }
  document.getElementById("eightball").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```